# Which one is correct: built or to be built

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, passive-voice

Which of these is correct?

> 1.How do you want your house **to be built**?
> 2.How do you want your house **built**?

I think 1 is correct because it is the house that **will be built**(someone will build it). But I can also get the same meaning with 2. So I don't know which one should be used. If 2 is correct and means the same, could you please explain the syntax?

And for these ones too:

> 3. When it was started to be built....
> 4. When it started to be built....

Comment: 1 and 2 are more or less the same. 3 is incorrect and 4 would be improved by inserting _being_ before built. It is still a bit clumsy though. I am afraid I have no knowledge of English grammar, I just speak it, so this is just a comment not a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you @mdewey it gave me a better understanding.